# Get a std::tuple element as std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17

Given a variant type:

```
using Variant = std::variant<bool, char, int, float, double, std::string>;
```

and a tuple type containing elements restricted to this variant types (duplicates and omissions are possible, but no additional types):

```
using Tuple = std::tuple<char, int, int, double, std::string>;
```

How to implement methods that gets and sets a tuple element by a given index as Variant at runtime:

```
Variant Get(const Tuple & val, size_t index);
void Set(Tuple & val, size_t index, const Variant & elem_v);
```

I have two implementations in my code, but I have an impression that there can be a better one. My first implementation uses `std::function` and the second builds an array of some `Accessor` pointers that imposes restrictions on moving and copying my object (because its address changes). I wonder if someone knows the right way to implement this.

**EDIT1:**

The following example probably clarifies what I mean:

```
Tuple t = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3, 5.0 "abc");
Variant v = Get(t, 1);
assert(std::get<int>(v) == 2);
Set(t, 5, Variant("xyz"));
assert(std::get<5>(t) == std::string("xyz"));
```

Comment: What would this even mean? Variant and tuple are really different things. Why are you going from one to the other?

Comment: @Barry Variant contains a tuple element. see EDIT1.

Comment: @Barry I don't believe OP wants to convert from one to the other. Rather, they seem to simply want to access a tuple element using an index that is not known at compile time, using an `std::variant` to account for the various possible types that element might have.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, I missed the `not` sorry.

Comment: Your `Set` function looks toxic.  The variant knows which is engaged.  Either index matches the one engaged (ok), or it doesn't (which means what, crash?  UB?  Throw?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to continue my theme of recommending Boost.Mp11 for all metaprogramming things, because there is always a function for that. In this case, we want [`mp_with_index`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_with_indexni_f). That function lifts a runtime index into a compile-time index.

```
Variant Get(Tuple const& val, size_t index)
{
    return mp_with_index<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>(
        index,
        [&](auto I){ return Variant(std::get<I>(val)); }
        );
}
```

Given that in the OP, the indices of the Tuple and the Variant don't even line up, the `Set` needs to actually visit the `Variant` rather than relying on the index. I'm using `is_assignable` here as the constraint, but that can be adjusted to as fitting for the problem (e.g. maybe it should be `is_same`).

```
void Set(Tuple& val, size_t index, Variant const& elem_v)
{
    mp_with_index<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>(
        index,
        [&](auto I){
            std::visit([&](auto const& alt){
                if constexpr (std::is_assignable_v<
                        std::tuple_element_t<Tuple, I>,
                        decltype(alt)>)
                {
                    std::get<I>(val) = alt;
                } else {
                    throw /* something */;
                }
            }, elem_v);
        });
}
```

If you require that every type in the `Tuple` appears exactly once in the `Variant`, and you want to directly only assign from that type without doing any conversions, this can be simplified to:

```
void Set(Tuple& val, size_t index, Variant const& elem_v)
{
    mp_with_index<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>(
        index,
        [&](auto I){
            using T = std::tuple_element_t<Tuple, I>;
            std::get<I>(val) = std::get<T>(elem_v);
        });
}
```

which will throw if the variant is not engaged with that type.

Comment: Is `I` implicitly a `constexpr`? I've never seen a function argument used as a template argument before.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `I` is an `integral_constant<size_t, K>` for some `K`, that type's conversion to `size_t` is a constant expression.

Comment: That makes sense. I never considered that `integral_constant` was implicitly convertible to it's `value_type`, I always used the `value` member.

Comment: The maximum template parameter in `mp_with_index` source code is 15. Does this mean that this code would not compile with Tuple or Variant containing 16 or more elements?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky That is incorrect. There is no such maximum.

Comment: @Barry: No? I'm seeing some evidence that there is. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/boost/mp11/detail/mp_with_index.hpp

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There is no maximum (modulo template instantiation limits, which probably gets you to around 2000).

Comment: @Barry What's going on with those overloads then?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There are specializations for 0 thru 16 and then the primary to handle > 16.

Answer (score 3):

Here are possible implementations of a `get_runtime` and `set_runtime` functions that rely on recursion to try to match the runtime index to a compile time one:

```
template <class Variant, class Tuple, std::size_t Index = 0>
Variant get_runtime(Tuple &&tuple, std::size_t index) {
    if constexpr (Index == std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Tuple>>) {
        throw "Index out of range for tuple";
    }
    else {
        if (index == Index) {
            return Variant{std::get<Index>(tuple)};
        }
        return get_runtime<Variant, Tuple, Index + 1>(
            std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), index);
    }
}


template <class Tuple, class Variant, std::size_t Index = 0>
void set_runtime(Tuple &tuple, std::size_t index, Variant const& variant) {
    if constexpr (Index == std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Tuple>>) {
        throw "Index out of range for tuple";
    }
    else {
        if (index == Index) {
            // Note: You should check here that variant holds the correct type
            // before assigning.
            std::get<Index>(tuple) = 
                std::get<std::tuple_element_t<Index, Tuple>>(variant);
        }
        else {
            set_runtime<Tuple, Variant, Index + 1>(tuple, index, variant);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use them like your `Get` and `Set`:

```
using Variant = std::variant<bool, char, int, float, double, std::string>;
using Tuple = std::tuple<char, int, int, double, std::string>;

Tuple t = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3, 5.0, "abc");
Variant v = get_runtime<Variant>(t, 1);
assert(std::get<int>(v) == 2);
set_runtime(t, 4, Variant("xyz"));
assert(std::get<4>(t) == std::string("xyz"));
```

Comment: why recursive functions but not fold expressions?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Because I am more familiar with these ;) I am not sure you would gain anything using fold expressions vs. these kind of compile-time recursions with optimization enabled.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Looking at other answers, I find that, in this case, fold expressions create messy codes, not that simple to understand, while with the availability of `if constexpr`, the recursive version are quite straightforward. But maybe there is a very nice implementation using fold expression somewhere ;)

Comment: yes, probably the recursion looks better than fake lambdas with fold expressions.

Comment: Did you compiled this? see https://wandbox.org/permlink/nzVOagQjwOKf45kY

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky I copy paste your example and forgot to fix the 5, you need to change it to 4. You also need to change `"xyz"` to `std::string{"xyz"}` or use the `s` literal because `"xyz"` will fill the variant with a `bool` value. See https://wandbox.org/permlink/JzRpvP4RqYYWmfyE

Answer (score 1):

```
template <size_t... I>
Variant GetHelper(const Tuple& val, size_t index, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    Variant value;
    int temp[] = {
        ([&]
        {
            if (index == I)
                value = std::get<I>(val);
        }(), 0)... };
    return value;
}

Variant Get(const Tuple& val, size_t index)
{
    return GetHelper(val, index, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>{});
}

template <size_t... I>
void SetHelper(Tuple& val, size_t index, Variant elem_v, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    int temp[] = {
        ([&]
        {
            using type = std::tuple_element_t<I, Tuple>;
            if (index == I)
                std::get<I>(val) = std::get<type>(elem_v);
        }(), 0)... };
}

void Set(Tuple& val, size_t index, Variant elem_v)
{
    SetHelper(val, index, elem_v, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>{});
}
```

Explanation:

Use `std::index_sequence` to get access to every tuple element via compile time constant index `I`. Create a lambda for each index, that performs the desired action if the index matches, and call it immediately (note the `()` right after the lambdas). Use the syntax `int temp[] = { (some_void_func(), 0)... }` to actually call every lambda (you cannot use the unpacking syntax `...` on void functions directly, hence this trick to assign it to an int array).

Alternatively, you can make your lambdas return some dummy int. Then you can call them via unpacking directly.

Answer (score 1):

First, some machinery.

`alternative` is a variant of integral constants, which are stateless.  We can then use visit on them to convert a bounded runtime value to a compile time value.

```
template<class T, T...Is>
using alternative = std::variant< std::integral_constant<T, Is>... >;

template<class List>
struct alternative_from_sequence;
template<class T, T...Is>
struct alternative_from_sequence< std::integer_sequence<T,Is...> > {
  using type=alternative<T, Is...>;
};
template<class T, T Max>
using make_alternative = typename alternative_from_sequence<
  std::make_integer_sequence<T, Max>
>::type;

template<class T, T Max, T Cur=Max-1>
make_alternative<T, Max> get_alternative( T value, std::integral_constant< T, Max > ={} ) {
  if(Cur == 0 || value == Cur) {
    return std::integral_constant<T, Cur>{};
  }
  if constexpr (Cur > 0)
  {
    return get_alternative<T, Max, Cur-1>( value );
  }
}
template<class...Ts>
auto get_alternative( std::variant<Ts...> const& v ) {
    return get_alternative<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts) >( v.index() );
}
```

now your actual problem.  This `Get` requires you pass your `Variant` type:

```
template<class Variant, class...Ts>
Variant Get(std::tuple<Ts...> const & val, size_t index) {
  auto which = get_alternative<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)>( index );
  return std::visit( [&val]( auto i )->Variant {
    return std::get<i>(val);
  }, which );
}
```

Your `Set` function seems toxic; if the types don't match, there is no practical recourse.  I'll add a return value that states if the assignment failed:

```
template<class...Ts, class...Vs>
bool Set(
  std::tuple<Ts...> & val,
  std::size_t index,
  const std::variant<Vs...>& elem_v
) {
  auto tuple_which = get_alternative<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)>( index );
  auto variant_which = get_alternative( elem_v );
  return std::visit( [&val, &elem_v](auto tuple_i, auto variant_i) {
    using variant_type = std::variant_alternative_t<variant_i, std::variant<Vs...>>;
    using tuple_type = std::tuple_element_t< tuple_i, std::tuple<Ts...> >;

    if constexpr (!std::is_assignable<tuple_type&, variant_type const&>{}) {
      return false;
    } else {
      std::get<tuple_i>(val) = std::get<variant_i>(elem_v);
      return true;
    }
  }, tuple_which, variant_which );
}
```

This `Set` returns false if the types are not assignable.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ca44f8a2b08c158).

Comment: variant knows the index of the type, but not the index of the element in tuple.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky They correspond exactly, don't they?  Oh, they don't.  Ok.

Comment: no, there can be multiple elements of the same type in the tuple, for example.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky What happens if your code requests that a `std::string` be copied over an `int`?  (or what is supposed to happen)

Comment: if you are asking about something like `Set(t, 1, Variant("xyz"));` - it is a type mismatch (there should be an exception or probably a conversion).

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky I made `Set` return `false` in that case.  There is no conversion from string to integer in C++.