# Constexpr lambda argument

Tags: c++, c++17

Is it possible to have a lambda with a constexpr argument? And is it possible to make the following example work?

`ForEach` function provided below calls a given lambda 3 times with index 0, 1, 2:

```
template <class Func, std::size_t... index>
inline constexpr void ForEach(Func && f, std::index_sequence<index...>)
{
    (f(index), ...);
}

template <class Func>
inline constexpr void ForEach(Func && f)
{
    ForEach(f, std::make_index_sequence<3>());
}
```

so the following code

```
ForEach([](size_t index)
{
    std::cout << index << ' ' << std::endl;
});
```

outputs 0, 1, 2.

But the following code that tries to print tuple elements requires `index` to be a constexpr:

```
auto t = std::make_tuple(1, 2.0, std::string("abc"));

ForEach([&t](size_t index)
{
    std::cout << std::get<index>(t) << ' ' << std::endl;
});
```

and thus does not compile, see [live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kF31Hh8hMWaUObCM). Is it possible to make `index` constexpr somehow?

**EDIT1:** There is a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56775116/get-a-stdtuple-element-as-stdvariant) where a lambda argument is used as a template argument:

```
void Set(Tuple& val, size_t index, Variant const& elem_v)
{
    mp_with_index<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>(
        index,
        [&](auto I){
            std::visit([&](auto const& alt){
                if constexpr (std::is_assignable_v<
                        std::tuple_element_t<Tuple, I>,
                        decltype(alt)>)
                {
                    std::get<I>(val) = alt;
                } else {
                    throw /* something */;
                }
            }, elem_v);
        });
}
```

why does this compile, but my sample code does not?

Comment: No. Function arguments can't be treated as `constexpr` (not sure whether `C++20` changes that).

Comment: @Fureeish see EDIT1. Why does it compile?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky `I` is a `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, (something)>` which has a `constexpr operator std::size_t()` that returns that `(something)`

Comment: @Fureeish It did not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this:

```
ForEach([&t](size_t index)
{
    std::cout << std::get<index>(t) << ' ' << std::endl;
});
```

`index` is not a constant expression. It's just a variable. Function parameters are not constexpr.

But if we tweaked `ForEach` somewhat (to work the same way as the example of mine that you linked):

```
template <class Func, std::size_t... index>
inline constexpr void ForEach(Func && f, std::index_sequence<index...>)
{
    (f(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, index>()), ...);
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    //    instead of just index
}

ForEach([&t](auto index)
{
    std::cout << std::get<index>(t) << ' ' << std::endl;
});
```

Then this works because `index` is no longer `size_t` but rather different instances of `std::integral_constant<size_t, V>` for various `V`. That type looks [something like](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant):

> ```
> template<class T, T v>
> struct integral_constant {
>     static constexpr T value = v;
>     typedef T value_type;
>     typedef integral_constant type; // using injected-class-name
>     constexpr operator value_type() const noexcept { return value; }
>     constexpr value_type operator()() const noexcept { return value; } //since c++14
> };
> ```

Converting a `std::integral_constant<size_t, V>` to a `size_t` invokes the `constepxr operator size_t()`, which doesn't involve reading any state from this object itself (which is an empty type), hence it's allowed as a constant expression.

A different way of looking at it is that we're encoding the value in the *type* (which can be retrieved as a constant expression) rather than in the *value* (which cannot).